# Python remove one worded strings from list

Tags: python

```
words = [['hey', 'hey you'], ['ok', 'ok no', 'boy', 'hey ma']]
```

I have a list of lists containing strings.  I understand how to remove specific elements from a list, but not how to remove those that are only one word.  My desired output would be:

```
final = [['hey you'], ['ok no', 'hey ma']]
```

What I'm trying but I think it's totally wrong....

```
remove = [' ']
check_list = []

for i in words:
    tmp = []
    for v in i:
        a = v.split()
        j = ' '.join([i for i in a if i not in remove])
        tmp.append(j)

    check_list.append(tmp)
print check_list
```

Comment: *"I think it's totally wrong"* - does it work? Have you *tested* it?

Comment: yes, ive tested it, but `check_list` outputs the same as `words`

Comment: Alright, so give a [mcve].

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Then read the link. Cut your code down and give example input with expected and actual output, so others don't have to comb through it.

Comment: I have example input and an expected output... I can't cut the code down anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
words = [['hey', 'hey you'], ['ok', 'ok no', 'boy', 'hey ma']]
final = [[x for x in sub if ' ' in x.strip()] for sub in words]
# [['hey you'], ['ok no', 'hey ma']]
```

where I simply search for spaces in all strings.

Comment: @PeterWood ... just corrected that by stripping the strings first

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`:

```
for words in list_of_lists: 
    words[:] = list(filter(lambda x: ' ' in x.strip(), words))
```

Or list comprehension:

```
for words in list_of_lists:
    words[:] = [x for x in words if ' ' in x.strip()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming way to do that:

```
>>> words
[['hey', 'hey you'], ['ok', 'ok no', 'boy', 'hey ma']]
>>> map(lambda v: ' '.join(v),
    filter(lambda y: len(y) > 1, map(lambda x: x.split(), words[1])))
['ok no', 'hey ma']
>>> map(lambda z: map(lambda v: ' '.join(v),
    filter(lambda y: len(y) > 1, map(lambda x: x.split(), z))), words)
[['hey you'], ['ok no', 'hey ma']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the logic for each list,  this you can loop and use

```
wordlist=['hey', 'hey you']
filter(None,  [ p if re.sub('\\b\\w+\\b', '', p) != '' else None for p in wordlist ])
```

output

```
['hey you']
```